# Rename Folder name when rename the tree node in the application

Tags: c#, winforms

i rename the treeview treenode in application using keyword F2. After Renaming this, this name change should happen in the directory also..How do i know i have done edited name and it is changed and where can i call change directory name method.

```
 private void treeView_project_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
            if (e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.F2)
            {
                treeView_Project.SelectedNode.BeginEdit();
//here it is editing the treenode once it is done user should rename the folder also in the drive
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the aptly-named [`AfterLabelEdit` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterlabeledit.aspx).

Comment: Yes after editing the label how can i get the previous name and renamed name

Comment: @Udhay: `e.Node.Text` and `e.Label`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the path of the directory, you can rename the directory with these lines:

```
            try
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
                di.MoveTo(di.Parent + "\\" + newName);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Changing directory name failed
            }
```

Comment: Yes, this is a **very** good answer! I, myself, store the path of the folders within a `TreeNode`'s name property, and your code is perfect for it :) +1 !